# Using Google + API and LinkedIn API within a desktop application (without prompting user for username-password)

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, google-plus

I'm going to create a page which will download user's activity and save it in an .xml file because my iphone app needs to process it. The problem is that I cannot prompt the user for login-password... so I was wondering if there is a sort of permanent key that I can use to access into linkedin and gplus?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google+**

I can field the Google+ part of your question :)

You can access your users' public activity using the REST API's [activity list method](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list). To identify who they are you'll need to send them through an [OAuth flow](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) during which they will authorize you to know who they are on Google+.

The best way to get started doing server side OAuth flows in Google+ is to grab one of the [starter projects](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/) and go through the included readme. That will give you a working project to copy code out of, or develop upon.

I'd include a code sample to show you how it works, but I don't know what would best apply to your back end :)

**Linkedin**

I'm far from an expert on their APIs, but it looks like the flow would be similar using [OAuth](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication).

Comment: yeah but my problem is that my application cannot use oauth, because it needs to be running in background, so it cannot show user any particular GUI... for example, for Twitter, I created to API Keys which I can use to call their APIs, without requiring any further action...